# Helper library for ASP.NET Core 5 - NuGet packages not available?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm writing a helper library for ASP.NET Core 5 (with .NET 5) and I need some APIs from the package [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core/). However, the package is only available in version 2.2 - not version 5.

Is ASP.NET Core no longer distributed via NuGet? And if so, how does one get the APIs with ASP.NET Core 5.

*Side note:* I found that I could use `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` as SDK for the project but I'm unsure whether this is a valid/good/correct approach when writing a *library*.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-libraries-via-multi-targeting

Comment: @davidfowl So, yes, ASP.NET Core is no longer distributed via NuGet, correct?

Comment: Pieces of it are, but the core framework is a single FrameworkReference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is ASP.NET Core no longer distributed via NuGet? And if so, how does one get the APIs with ASP.NET Core 5.

That's correct. The core of ASP.NET Core (no pun intended...) ships with .NET Core >= 3.0 as a shared framework. You can add a single FrameworkReference to your nuget package to pull this in. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-libraries-via-multi-targeting for more information.

Some background can be found here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/3756

Comment: An even more precise link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#use-the-aspnet-core-shared-framework